# How can I perform server-side API requests in my client-side rendered React app?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, server, server-side-rendering, react-dom

I have a React app where I need to perform API calls that involve sensitive credentials in the request body. I'm concerned about rendering the whole app server-side, Is there a way to ensure that the API calls are executed server-side to prevent the exposure of sensitive data?

I have a basic understanding of both SSR and CSR, so i'm unsure if my desired outcome is achievable. Specifically, I'm unsure if server-side API calls require server-side rendering, especially in React 18.

Comment: Why not make your own backend/API which does the calls to the authenticated external API's and returns that to your React app? No need for SSR. So: your react app -> your api -> external api

Comment: But in the stage of deploying how can i handle the Express.js server when I only have an Apache server where I plan to build the React app and host it?